# How to Put Product Manually and send mail when user subscribe newsletter in magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, newsletter

In magento2 when a customer subscribes newsletter at that time `"successfully subscribe message"` sent to customers.
This is Default functionality of Magento2

Here I want to send the specific product in subscription mail when the customer subscribes newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by modifying **vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model::subscribe($email)**. You can see it is sending confirmation email using function **sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()**. You need to add the required product data using email variables and than update the template with your custom content/product details. You can use plugin/preference to these functions/model to achieve it in much better way.

OR

You can also send a separate email by using Magento events like **"newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after"** with required product details.

Comment: Can you describe in more brief @Himmat Pallwal